# How do I make a Minecraft render similar to the graphics from trailers/teasers for updates?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, edges, shader-nodes

Actually, I want to make the appearance of my renders close to what I presented in the pictures, I will even attach those works that I have already been able to do and which look as close as possible to how it is done on professional renders. However, still the renders (not mine) look much better than my own. Please help me, give me ideas on how I can make the renders better, closer to what I want.

[image: Highlights]
[image: Highlights]
[image: Highlights]

Next are my own renders:

[image: My highlights]
[image: My highlights]

One of the main differences that I see myself, but I can't do anything in my renderings is that the highlights are "made" mostly not from the brighter colors of the object, but rather from the contour light (rim lights, idk), or just the light in the scene. Is there any way I can apply the light in the frame to my highlights? If so, how?

Comment: If you're using flat white background, the lighting on the model will be even and not as dynamic as your examples.  You have to tell the background to only show to the camera, and then light your scene as desired.

Comment: I use a transparent background, not a white one. This is how the image was uploaded to the site.

Comment: Really nice work you did there!
I have also been craving a lot to achieve this shader. I got most of the inspiration from [Hapico](https://www.youtube.com/@Hapico/videos) (a YouTube channel).[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNWVU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNWVU.jpg) This is what I achieved recently on Eevee engine.
I used bevel modifier and material indexing to form this brightly colored outline.
For most entities I have used inverted hull (solidify modifier).